# KeyboardAvoidingView has no effect

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I am trying to use keyboard avoiding view for not hiding my input element. I have tried multiple ways but its not working for me and elements still get hidden for some reason!
Can anyone help me figure out why?
As you see below the "notes" input section and the continue button is getting hidden, even though I'm using KeyboardAvoidingView component.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.wrapper}>
            {steps.map((s, index) => {
              return (
                <SlideAnimation
                  style={styles.slide}
                  open={index == step}
                  key={s.title}
                >
                  <Stack key={s.title} direction="column">
                    <AnimatedSizeText selected={index == step}>
                      {`${index + 1}. ${s.title}`}
                    </AnimatedSizeText>

                    {s.content}
                  </Stack>
                </SlideAnimation>
              );
            })}
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

[image]
[image]

Details:
"expo": "^45.0.6",
"react-native": "0.68.2",

Answer (score 0):

Had to use behavior='position'